# How to delete the row in datagrid

Tags: vb.net

using Vb.net

datagrid

```
id value

01 Rajan
02 Raman
03 Suresh
.....
```

textbox1.text = `01/02`

So i want to remove the id 01, 02 from datagrid.

Tried Code ' For Splitting the value from textbox using array

```
Dim zValue As String
Dim splitBySlash As String()
zValue = textbox1.text
splitBySlash = zValue.Split("/")
```

Now i want to pass this array value for removing the row from datagrid.

How to do this.

Need vb.net code help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be somewhat pseudo code so dont just copy and past and expect it to work. There are also many more ways to do this... And this also means that Datagrid is a Datagridview and that Id is the first column. I'm not sure but datagrid.Rows(i).Cells("id") might work too.

```
For each s as String in splitBySlash
   For i as integer = 0 To datagrid.Rows.Count - 1
       if datagrid.Rows(i).Cells(0).ToString = s Then
           datagrid.Rows.RemoveAt(i)
           Exit for
       end if
   Next
Next
```